# Add new activity in place of Main activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to Android. I want to create a new activity(*UserList.java*) and replace it with Main Activity, such that when app starts, Userlist should run rather than MainActivity.
I want to know what are all the changes(manifest, implementing methods) needed to be done.

Note: I have already tried changing in the manifest file, but it throws an error saying `Default activity not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both `MainActivity` and `UserList` are already registered in the manifest, you should have something like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".UserList" />
```

To make `UserList` the launch Activity instead, just move the `intent-filter` from `MainActivity` to `UserList`, like so:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

    <activity android:name=".UserList">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks, keeping the MainActivity above UserList helped with the situation

Answer (score 0):

use `intent-filter` inside `UserList` activity in **AndroidManifest.xml** and remove this `intent-filter` for `MainActivity`

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure you have added this in the manifest file.

inside the desired activity

```
<activity>
  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>
```

> Make sure you remove the intent-filter from the mainActivity

Answer (score 0):

First make sure Your class UserList extends AppCompatActivity.
Then try to change the ".MainActivity" to ".UserList".
When you will press "." UserList name will popup in android studio select that.If the popup not showing that mean you UserList class not extending AppCompatActivity or Actvitiy class.
[image]